# Can't install Delphi Community Edition

Tags: delphi

I uninstalled my current version (trial) of Delphi 10.2 and want to install the Community Edition.

I keep getting a message:

"A previous version of Rad Studio 10.2 was found on your system that needs to be uninstalled first. Do you want to remove all Rad Studio 10.2 entries from your registry?"

I select "YES" and I get the following message:

"The Previous version is not removed. Unable to continue"

I cant go any farther!

I have removed everything I could find related to "Embarcadero", "Delphi", "Rad Studio" and even "Borland"

I also followed the directions found here:

[Manual uninstall of RAD Studio/Delphi/C++Builder 10.2](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-support/174-rad-studio/installation-registration/16501-manual-uninstall-of-rad-studio-delphi-c-builder-10-2)

Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked through the Registry for those strings? [Editing the Registry for the *many* entries is a pain, and could cause issues if mistakes are made, but sometimes it's the only way to uninstall completely.]

Comment: Yes, everything I could find on the drive and in the registry!

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried to see if there isn't mayne a license stored somewhere? (I can't think of anything else since you've already uninstalled and removed everything including the registry)